# Separating Arrays As Variables-PHP

Tags: php, dynamic-arrays

How can I use the second array as a seperate variable? 
and print it as, for example, a link.

My current code is:

```
$result = $query->product('1149632')  
->show(array('name','image','salePrice','url', 'sku'))->query();  

print <<<THIS  
<div>$result</div>  

THIS;
```

Thanks

Comment: Second array? I only see one in your sample.

Comment: My bad, I mean the values of the resulting array; Is it possible to seperate and print the values

Comment: do you mean <a href='{$result['url']}'>{$result['name']}</a> ?

Comment: or if you;re returning them as an object  <a href='{$result->url}'>{$result->name}</a>

Comment: I could not get those to work using the <<<THIS THIS;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that `$query()` method call returns an array, then you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($result as $val) {
    echo "<div>$val</div>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"
    <div><a href='{$result['url']}'>{$result['name']}</a> ${$result['salePrice']}</div>  

";
```

Comment: Your example would produce an error because you are creating [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) by calling `${$result['salePrice']}`